# 0 bytes file while copying data between S3 Buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

While copying data from one S3 bucket to another using cp command, there is an additional 0 bytes file created in the target folder.

Eg. aws cp "s3://A/" "s3://B/" --recursive (Here, B folder is not present already so it will be created while copying the data)

This 0 bytes file is not visible on console but while I list the files on command line, I see that file. Why and how is that created? Is there a way to avoid it?

Also, noticed that aws sync command does not create that 0 bytes file. Is sync the better approach to copying files?

Comment: S3 typically does not have actual folders. It has virtual folders, inferred from the available S3 object keys. For example if `s3://mybucket/dog/fido.png` exists then there's a virtual folder `dog/`. What is the 0 byte file that is created? Is it an object representing the source 'folder' so it has key `A/` and is 0 bytes? If so, that suggests that `A/` was created as a folder using the AWS console and there is an object with that key, hence it is being synced (because it's an actual object).